Performance issue in JakartaEE application containered inside a Apache TomEE 9.1.2(Pulme) application server
One request for my application will create 5 threads for 5 parallel calls but for some reason TomEE is not giving enough threads for the internal processing as I can see, it is able to handle 5 req/second where as the same application when developed using spring boot can handle upto 30 req/sec.
I have tried Managed executor configuration in TomEE this didn't work as expected, and tried to configure Executor service this configuration don't have an effect at all. Please suggest how to do configuration to increase number of threads available.
With an average response time of 2 seconds to process atleast 20 request per second I need 100 threads minimum.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

After some investigation I learnt that the bottleneck is the EJB pool
